# Limit of $\lim_{x \to \pi/4} = \frac{1-\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)(\cos(x)-\sin(x))}$

Tags: limits

I have to explain how to solve this equation to phi/4. In general, I would just deriviate this equation, however, this has to be done on the traditional way (as simplifying this formula).

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/4}  \frac{1-\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)(\cos(x)-\sin(x))}$$

I tried using to subsitute $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$, by $2\sin (x) \cos (x)$ and $1-2 \sin ^2(x)$, respectively, but that didn't seem to work out.

Would any of you have a possible suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Question doesn’t make sense as it is currently phrased.  The problem asks about a "limit" as $x$ tends to "phi/4", so Readers will expect to be told of an expression involving $x$ whose limit is sought and what "phi/4" means.  Perhaps the expression involving $x$ is the right hand side, but this needs clarification.

Comment: @hardmath its $\frac{\pi}{4}$ I think.

Comment: L'Hopital works, but you will have to applu it twice.

Comment: Indeed Archis, apologies. Still trying to figure out how to use the format for formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$1-\sin2x=(\cos x-\sin x)^2$$

$$\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$$

$$x\to\dfrac\pi4,\cos x-\sin x\to0,$$

$$\cos x-\sin x\ne0$$ hence can be cancelled safely from denominator and numerator

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1-\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)(\cos x-\sin x)} = \frac{1+\cos(2(\frac{\pi}{4}+x))}{\cos(2x)\sqrt2\bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin x\bigg]} = \frac{2\cos^2\bigg[\frac{\pi}{4}+x\bigg]}{\sqrt2\cos(2x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}=\frac{\sqrt2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}{\cos(2x)}$$

So,

$$L = \lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}{\cos(2x)} = \lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt2\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}{2\sin(2x)} = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}  =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$